# Window changes on different screens

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I recently started learning PyQT5 and designed a user-interface using Qt Designer.
But, when I run my program and move the main window from one monitor to another,
the appearance of the window changes.

I am not sure how to keep it constant.
I have kept the window size fixed at 830 x 600 pixels.

The first image is from the bigger (24-inch 1080p) monitor and the second image is from the smaller (15-inch 1080p) monitor.

[image: Screenshot of the window on my 24-inch display]

[image: Screenshot of window on my 15-inch display]

Comment: It looks like you're not using layouts (or at least not using them consistently).

Comment: PS: the [Qt article on High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) has some useful general information that is applicable for all kinds of displays.